# How to install and use CMIS Workbench

Tags: cmis

I want to browse my repository *(Alfresco, Documentum, SharePoint, FileNet, NemakiWare, etc)*.

How to do this with Apache CMIS Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install Java if you do not have it yet.

Second, download the latest version of CMIS Workbench. To do that, [go to the OpenCMIS Downloads page](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html) and find the "OpenCMIS Workbench" line. Click the "Download" link at that line. The download is a ZIP file, so just unzip it and execute the `workbench.bat` file if you are on Windows, or the `workbench.sh` if you are on Linux/Mac (change its properties to make it executable if needed). The following window will appear:

[image: CMIS Workbench login]

Enter the CMIS URL of your repository (if you don't know it, [find the pattern of your server](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/wiki/What-address) or ask your administrator), and your username/password, then click `Load Repositories`, then `Login`. Don't forget the URL's `https` or `http` prefix and port number. That's it! After a few seconds to a minute, the content of your repository should appear:

[image]